# Network calls within Electron React app

Tags: ajax, sockets, reactjs, electron

I'm new to electron and I want to make sure I understand the distinction between code that is appropriate for the main process vs the renderer process. The app is essentially a React app hosted inside a single electron page. So, as I understand it, I have one main process and one render process.

If I want to make REST calls as part of the React app (using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) for example), I assume I can do it inside the React code within the renderer process, right? No need to go to the main process for that is there?

I also have to create a socket connection to an outside server. This is not an HTTP REST interface, it's a raw TCP/IP socket. Can this also be done within the renderer process or do I need to go to the main for that?

I tried putting the socket calls using node's [net](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net) library and it seems to work okay. The very first time I got some kind of connection error but subsequent tries seem to be working. That one error is making me wonder if using `net` inside the renderer is a good idea though.